# Program stops after taking value

Tags: c++

I am writing this code for prime numbers; after taking inputs from the user the program is not doing any further calculations.
An example of input/output would be:

```
Enter the Number You Want to Check::67
```

After the input, the program doesn't show whether the number is prime or not.
Here is the code:

```cpp
int main() {
  int i, n;
  cout << "Enter the Number You Want to Check::";
  cin >> n;
  if (n == 1) {
    cout << "Smallest Prime number is 2;" << endl;
  }
  for (i == 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      cout << "No is not prime";
      break;
    }
  }
  if (n == i) {
    cout << "Number is prime";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, check the for loop usage. [for loop reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

Comment: Why do you have a quote at the beginning of the program?  That surely must be a typo.  And also, could you please make sure your formatting is correct?  It's hard to read badly indented code (or in this case, code with no indentation at all)

Answer (score 5):

```
int i, n;
...
for(i==2;i<n;i++)
```

That's bogus. You have never initialized `i`.

I suspect you wanted to write

```
int i, n;
...
for(i=2;i<n;i++)
```

that is; make the first term of the `for` loop an assignment to `i` rather than a comparison with `2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i== 2; i < n; i++)
```

This starts the loop by checking whether `i` is 2. Try setting `i` to 2:

```
for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
```

Also, before the loop, you check whether `n` is `1`, but not whether it's less than `1`. `0` is divisible by all primes, but `-1` is not.

Answer (score 1):

In this for statement

```
for(i==2;i<n;i++)
```

you are using the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`. Write instead

```
for(i=2;i<n;i++)
```

In fact there is no need to use the following condition `i<n` in the loop because when `i` is greater than `n / i` `n % i` never can be equal to `0`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the number of iterations of the loop can be decreased.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n  ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        unsigned int i = 2;
        while ( ( i <= n / i ) and ( n % i != 0 ) ) i++;

        if ( ( n == 1 ) or ( i <= n / i ) )
        {
            std::cout << "No, " << n << " is not prime.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The number " << n << " is prime.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 1
No, 1 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 2
The number 2 is prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 3
The number 3 is prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 4
No, 4 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 5
The number 5 is prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 6
No, 6 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 7
The number 7 is prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 8
No, 8 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 9
No, 9 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 10
No, 10 is not prime.
Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): 0
```

You could write a separate function that determines whether a given number is prime.

A more efficient approach is to exclude even values (except 2) from the set of prime numbers.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the Number You Want to Check (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n  ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        bool prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

        for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime and i <= n / i; i += 2 )
        {
            prime = n % i;
        }

        if ( prime )
        {
            std::cout << "The number " << n << " is prime.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No, " << n << " is not prime.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look the same as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Variable initialization within the loop is wrong. It should be like below

```
for(i=2;i<n;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i==2;i<n;i++)
```

probably a typo error